# Apple Watch app getting data when iOS app starts

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I'm little confused with `WatchConnectivity`.

I can send data to the watch app from the iOS app. However, I only send data when the iOS app is started or active.

I want the watch app to request data from the iOS app. The watch application should request the information when it starts.

Comment: Why not use `updateApplicationContext` from iOS to watchOS and when the watchOS app is launched get the data. You can change the data as you like and you are guaranteed that the watchOS app will get the latest data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a user information and watch application should request these information when it starts.

When the user glances at their watch, why should they have to wait while data is requested, received, then updated in the app?

Instead of designing the watch app to retrieve the information when the user starts the app, you should consider other approaches to [keep your watch app up to date](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/218/).

- For watchOS 2, there are other ways to transfer current details in the background, such as `updateApplicationContext`, [which Ahmed mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745741/applewatch-getting-data-when-ios-app-starts#comment64865824_38745741).
- For watchOS 3, you can also use refresh tasks to update your watch app in the background.

Either of these approaches ensure that the information is *already* on hand, so the user doesn't have endure waiting for the watch app to update itself.

Comment: I used updateApplicationContext however in the first place watch app should request user's data. I'm updating application context when specific events(log out or log in) in iOS app happened. Actually I'm confused with structure for example I implemeted singleton class for watch connectivity and I create an object in appdelegate. Is it correct approach for this scenario?

Comment: Comments aren't a place to ask unrelated questions about your code. If the phone updates application (user data) context when the user logs in or out, why would the watch need to request the data?  Either the user is logged in, and the watch already has that data, or the user is logged out, and the watch knows that too. What data would the watch *still* need to request from the phone? If your question isn't answered, you should edit it and add specific details (e.g. explain what the watch specifically needs to request, show your code, and explain what's not working the way you expect).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. Data was only sent to the watch if I started the iOS App.
I solved it by sending a message with a replyhandler to the iOS app in the session activationDidCompleteWith - method of the watch. It does not need to send any specific message or reply. After the message was sent to the iOS app the updateApplicationContext fired and sent the data to watch.

EDIT: After some studying it seems that the session on iOS-side is not activated when the first data from the watch is "arriving" that's why it cannot answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can possibly use `sendMessage` method [link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:), which is part of the [WCSession class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/). The method takes a reply handler:

> A reply handler for receiving a response from the counterpart. Specify nil if you do not want to receive a reply.

So you can effectively notify the iOS app by sending a message with a reply handler which the iOS app uses to send data back.